# Updating PHP version in a VPS host

Tags: .htaccess, hosting

We want to update the PHP version for our site hosted in a virtual server, from 5.2.17 to 5.3, but haven't been able to do it.

We asked the ISP for instructions but they take some days to answer and we need to update it as soon as possible.

If anybody could at least give us a suggestion or guide to achieve it, we'll be really grateful.

Comment: Can you give some details on your OS?

Comment: It is an Apache server 2.2 with Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use your own php.ini in public_html but would have to configure it and that's not a good idea.

The best thing to do is to use the ISP ini files. This should work for any ISP:

.1 Find out where the ini file for the PHP version you need is located .

The path should be something like `/usr/local/phpNN/lib/php.ini` where NN is 53, for example.

.2 Login to your site account using (Bash) SSH. You can download `Putty` to do it, in case you don't have a suitable application.

.3 Copy the corresponding `php.ini` to your home directory with a command like this one:

`cp /usr/local/phpNN/lib/php.ini ~/php.ini`

.4 Add this at the end of .htaccess file at `/public_html`:

`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php`

`SuPHP_ConfigPath /home/MyAccountName`

.5 Confirm the PHP version with this code:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Comment: ok, we found out where the 5.3 version is using Filezilla with ssh. Can't we use it to move the file too?

Comment: You need to issue a command. That's not possible with Filezilla. Google for `Putty`

Comment: It looked complicated at first, but ended up being pretty easy. We solved our problem, thank you very much. Great help.